# Is it possible to call a repository from a thread in Java?

Tags: java, mongodb

I'm trying to use MongoRepository inside a thread. Is that possible?

For example, in a service, that repository goes in the constructor and then you can call it. But how can I do a query inside a thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of going directly with thread, you can use `@Async` annotation of spring boot.

```
public interface MyRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
@Async
Future<User> findByFirstname(String firstname);  
}
```

please see spring data jpa docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help someone.
I created a @Service and called it inside the thread, so finally I could use @Repository.